# Problems substituting table name into variable

Tags: php, html

i'm splitting the character from `$rg` and matching with the table name by using    `strstr` string function. i stored table name in array. string function returns like
`cs_branch` i pass this to the sql query. but it is not matching with table name in present in database.....

```
<?php
 $rg="175cs11011";
 $arr=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/','',$rg);

 $br=array("cs_branch","ce_branch");
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","6semcs") or die(MySQL_error());
 mysql_select_db("gptistu_progress") or die(MySQL_error());  
 for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
 {
   $ma=strstr($br[$i],$arr);
    echo $ma;
    $data ="SELECT * FROM `$ma`"; 
 }
 MySQL_query($data) or die(MySQL_error()); 
 ?>
```

Comment: "*It is not working*" is not useful. Please explain, if you get an error message (if so, which one) or if the results differ from your expectation (if so, how).

Comment: `mysql_connect("local host","root","6semcs")`  shouldn't this been localhost without an space?

`mysql_connect("localhost","root","6semcs")`

Comment: @MichaelDibbets good eyes....

Comment: What are the actual table names?

Comment: sir i'm splitting the character form 175cs11011 and matching with the table name. so i used four table name in array. and i used string compare function 'strstr' it returns me as 'cs_branch'. so i'm giving that character in sql query like this " $data ="SELECT * FROM `$ma`"; "

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
{
    $ma=strstr($br[$i],$arr);
    echo $ma;
    $data ="SELECT * FROM `$ma`"; 
}
```

With

```
foreach($br as $tableName) {
    $data ="SELECT * FROM `" . $tableName . "`"; 
}
```

p.s. Probably your **mysql_query()** must be in cycle too.

Comment: sir i'm splitting the character form 175cs11011 and matching with the table name. so i used four table name in array. and i used string compare function 'strstr' to match splitted character and table name,it return's me as cs_branch. and i'm giving that character in sql query like this " $data ="SELECT * FROM `$ma`"; "........

Answer (score 0):

Change `

```
mysql_connect("local host","root","6semcs") or die(MySQL_error());`
```

with

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","6semcs") or die(MySQL_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using substr wrong. Second argument must be an integer like:

```
substr($br[$i], strlen($arr))
```